# Docker-Compose Ports

Tags: django, docker, mariadb, containers, port

compose file
i want to connect my django container to my maria_db container
but when i specify port 3306 in django it work fine but when i specify port 3307 to django it fail although my maria_db port sets to "3307:3306" does anybody can explain how that possible?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFYDr.png)

[image]

try to connect maria_db to my django container with port 3307

Comment: Please post code/text itself, not _screenshots_ of text.

Comment: did you exposed 3307 port in django service?

Comment: Connections between containers neither use nor require `ports:`, they always connect to the "normal" port for the destination service.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify `PORTS` in your docker-compose file as this will only expose it to the outside. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

If you don't need external access to the database, remove the `PORTS` section from your docker-compose file and connect to the db with host `maria-db-users` and port `3306` (default MariaDB port).